# Jasmine array.length expect

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm just new to the jasmine js test framework and got some odd results today.

See the following code (`search` is a function that preforms an api request and returns a promise):

```
it('should be able to search', function() {
    search('string').done(function(result) {
        expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(1); //true
        console.log(result.lenght); // undefined
    });
});
```

The thing is that, due to some errors that I have to fix, the result from the promise is undefined, but the test is marked as `Success`. I find this misleading and if I din't investigate this deeply I would have believed that the test was a success while it clearly wasn't. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 17):

You have typo in console.log(result.lenght)  please try this.

```
it('should be able to search', function() {
search('string').done(function(result) {
    expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(1); //true
    console.log(result.length); // undefined
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For testing *asynchronous* functions, your tests need to be written slightly differently. From the latest [Jasmine (2.0) documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html), asynchronous test are written as follows:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do setup for spec here

        // then call done() in beforeEach() to start asynchronous test
        done();
    }, 1);
});

it('should be able to search', function(done) {
    search('string').done(function(result) {
        expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(1); //true

        // call done() in the spec when asynchronous test is complete
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: I decided to stop looking for a way to do requirejs based testing as i'm getting a bit irritated, will look again at it in a few days/weeks. Thanks for your contribution!